# Java implicitly calls intValue when passing Integer as argument

Tags: java, methods, integer, primitive-types, implicit-methods

So I came across a bug caused by following example:
I have static method

```
private static Foo findFoo(int id) {
  //we use id here not important
}
```

Then I used it inside another method like

```
private static updateFoo(final Integer id, final String newData) {
  final Foo existingData = findFoo(id);
  // use existing data and update or make new
}
```

The problem is when `updateFoo` is called with `null` in `id` argument, the `intValue()` is implicitly called (I think) when calling `findFoo(id)` and causes NPE.

I thought Java enforces strong typing that prevents cases where Objects are passed to arguments when primitives are expected. Is there a general rule here when implitic calls are made? And could this be picked up by compiler/IDE and possibly enforce or warn?

Comment: This is expected behavior called Unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

This always happens if you use a wrapper class as its primitive counter-part. `int` cannot be null, so you must call `intValue()` onto the wrapper class.

You can either do a null check before calling `findFoo()` or just use the primitive `int` for `updateFoo()` or the wrapper class in `findFoo()`.

> I thought Java enforces strong typing that prevents cases where Objects are passed to arguments when primitives are expected.

The type of Integer fits, so its type is covered. It is just an implicite casting (unboxing) in this case which is totally fine.